# Logic AND for Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to set to checked a checkbox input by value AND name..

```
<input name="email" type="checkbox" value="1" tabindex="2">
```

How can I do that? I need that both conditions are done.

This fails on &&

```
$("input[name=email] && [value='+i+']").attr('checked', true);
```

This code is into a for iteration and "i" is taking a numeric value.
Thanks in advance for your time and help...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use both selectors next to each other:

```
$("input[name=email][value=" + i + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Any selectors that have no space between them are applied to the same element.

Comment: Eloquent in brevity.  Thank you, sir!